# AEM/sightly : How to remove unicode in a page source code

Tags: html, unicode, aem, sightly

when checking at the source code of my page, i can see that some special characters such as " ' " or " & " have been replaced by their unicode value. This cause some problem SEO wise and i would like to make sure that unicode symbols get appropriately rendered. Where do i start from there ?

The page is rendered via AEM using sightly as a templating engine

[image]

Comment: "This cause some problem SEO wise" — Really? What search engine has that much trouble with basic HTML?

Comment: I'm not really familiar as to why exactly, we have a SEO specialist team who brought up this issue. I guess it shows up on their report when they do some page scanning and affect the overall score given.

Comment: While the single quote (`'`) _may_ be used unescaped (except in attributes, when delimited by single quotes themselves), `&` may not ever be used unescaped in HTML. To me it seems your SEO specialist may not be such a specialist after all.
Also, I don’t see anything wrong with the apostrophe (the one inside the meta description). Why did you highlight it?

Comment: If you just always want to use apostrophes (`’`) instead of single quotes (`'`) because the former don’t have to be escaped, teach your editors how to type them and tell them to use those in the titles.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a different [display context](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context) for your title, for example `<title>${page.title @ context="html"}</title>`, if that works for your application/site.